# Reconocimiento de palabras aisladas ¿Cómo leer los resultados de la MFCC y DTW?

Tags: calculo

Se trata de reconocimiento de palabras aisladas. Tengo un corpus de aprendizaje y uno de test con audios de palabras (uno por cada palabra). Gracias a Praat obtengo la MFCC de cada palabra. Por ejemplo:

```
File type = "ooTextFile"
Object class = "MFCC 1"

xmin = 0 
xmax = 1.244920634920635 
nx = 121 
dx = 0.01 
x1 = 0.02246031746031751 
fmin = 0 
fmax = 3900 
maximumNumberOfCoefficients = 37 
frame []: 
    frame [1]:
        numberOfCoefficients = 6 
        c0 = 739.4967520397784 
        c []: 
            c [1] = -17.706854515821973 
            c [2] = 68.74208039764812 
            c [3] = 19.417181363049988 
            c [4] = 18.23020375368816 
            c [5] = 26.51577939943669 
            c [6] = 4.862083512334764
```

Luego comparo cada palabra y obtengo la DTW (con Praat)

```
91.69273804739957 (= distance at (0.1, 0.1))
140.1880158235773 (weighted distance)
```

Sin embargo no se como "leer" el resultado. ¿Cómo sé cual es la tasa de reconocimiento? ¿Cuales son los datos que debo tomar en cuenta para saber si reconocio o no a la palabra?